# Если не прикидываться, что вводное образует оборот, то как быть с закрытием псевдооборота?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

> У нашего друга, большого любителя классической архитектуры и
>   выпускника архитектурной академии, есть самая настоящая мания – он
>   хочет привезти домой из Рима акант. В прошлый приезд присматривался,
>   видимо даже прочитал таможенные правила, и вот вчера нашел то место,
>   где акант растёт в изобилии.

*В прошлый приезд присматривался, видимо, даже прочитал таможенные правила (ПУСТО) и вот вчера нашёл то место, где акант растёт в изобилии, -*

так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вводное слово стоит на границе однородных членов, и не очень ясно, куда оно относится. Может быть, его переместить в середину?

В прошлый приезд, **видимо,**  присматривался, даже прочитал таможенные правила и вот вчера нашёл то место, где акант растёт в изобилии.

**ПАС § 94.** Вводные слова и сочетания слов, **стоящие на границе однородных членов** или частей сложного предложения и относящиеся к следующему за ними слову или предложению, **не отделяются от него запятой** (вторая запятая опускается с целью указания на отнесенность вводного слова к последующей части предложения):

Лось шел скачками в сторону озер, должно быть спешил на водопой (Пауст.); Послышался резкий стук, должно быть сорвалась ставня (Ч.).

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=127#pp127

Comment: А если не переставлять? У нас ясно, к чему относится вводное; в оригинале: *, видимо даже прочитал таможенные правила, и вот*...

Comment: Тогда (если это ясно),  запятая по правилам ПАС не ставится.

Comment: Обратно не поняла: жёлтенький варьянт верен или курсивный (мой)?

Comment: Думаю, что верен желтенький (без обособления вводного слова "видимо").